# Inserting strings with `<plug>` inside `<cmd>`

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript

When using `<cmd>...<cr>`, there are some special keys such as `<plug>` or `<cmd>` that are not allowed to be contained inside the block. Trying to execute the command will result in:

```
E5521: <Cmd> mapping must end with <CR> before second <Cmd>
```

```
E5522: <Cmd> mapping must not include <Plug> key
```

However, sometimes these special keys may appear in the mapping, not to be executed, but inside strings. A practical example is [vim-repeat](https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat). If you want to set it up by calling `repeat#set`, there'll most likely be a `<plug>` key in the string passed to the function:

```
<cmd>call repeat#set("\<Plug>MyWonderfulMap", v:count)<cr>
```

The "`\<Plug>`" should not part of the execution, but simply part of the string. However, the above will still fail, since `<Plug>` is still between `<cmd>` and `<cr>`. We are forced to use the `:` alternative:

```
:call repeat#set("\<Plug>MyWonderfulMap", v:count)<cr>
```

This is sub-optimal however, since it does not work for insert and visual modes.

So knowing that, is there a way to pass the key `<plug>` inside a function, without it being caught by the `<cmd>...<cr>` block?

Comment: One option that doesn't involve tricky escapes is to define a new function (and use `<Plug>` etc. in its body) and then call that function from the `<Cmd>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible if you manage escaping rules very carefully.  For example,

```
nnoremap x <cmd>echo "<bslash><lt>Plug>MyWonderfulMap" v:count<cr>
```

Then `:map x` prints:

```
n  x           * <Cmd>echo "\<Plug>MyWonderfulMap" v:count<CR>
```

And typing `3x` echos, as expected,

```
<80><fd>SMyWonderfulMap 3
```

Breaking what is happening here down by interpolation step:

1. `nnoremap` substitutes all the `<>` escape codes, `<bslash>` becomes `\` and `<lt>` becomes `<`.
2. when the map is executed, normal double quotes rules substitutes `\<Plug>` with the sequence `<80><fd>S` which is vim's way of denoting plug maps.